# How can I convert unicode to string of a dataframe column?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, unicode-string

I have a spark dataframe which has a column 'X'.The column contains elements which are in the form:

> u'[23,4,77,890,455,................]'

. How can I convert this unicode to list.That is my output should be

> [23,4,77,890,455...................]

.  I have apply it for each element in the 'X' column.

I have tried df.withColumn("X_new", ast.literal_eval(x)) and got the error

> "Malformed String"

I also tried

> df.withColumn("X_new", json.loads(x)) and got the error "Expected
>   String or Buffer"

and

> df.withColumn("X_new", json.dumps(x)) which says JSON not
>   serialisable.

and also

> df_2 = df.rdd.map(lambda x: x.encode('utf-8')) which says rdd has no
>   attribute encode.

I dont want to use collect and toPandas() because its memory consuming.(But if thats the only way please do tell).I am using Pyspark

**Update: cph_sto gave the answer using UDF.Though it worked well,I find that it is Slow.Can Somebody suggest any other method?**

Comment: Is it `890,455` or `890.455`?

Comment: How do we know whether `455` is part of decimal or just another number? If `comma` is your delimiter, then python or for that matter any language has no way of knowing whether the next number has to be interpreted as decimal or proper number. You must specify some condition to differentiate decimal comma (`European format`) from other `delimiter` comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import ast
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
values = [(u'[23,4,77,890.455]',10),(u'[11,2,50,1.11]',20),(u'[10.05,1,22.04]',30)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['list','A'])
df.show()
+-----------------+---+
|             list|  A|
+-----------------+---+
|[23,4,77,890.455]| 10|
|   [11,2,50,1.11]| 20|
|  [10.05,1,22.04]| 30|
+-----------------+---+    

# Creating a UDF to convert the string list to proper list
string_list_to_list = udf(lambda row: ast.literal_eval(row))
df = df.withColumn('list',string_list_to_list(col('list')))
df.show()
+--------------------+---+
|                list|  A|
+--------------------+---+
|[23, 4, 77, 890.455]| 10|
|   [11, 2, 50, 1.11]| 20|
|   [10.05, 1, 22.04]| 30|
+--------------------+---+
```

Extension of the `Q`, as asked by OP -

```
# Creating a UDF to find length of resulting list.
length_list = udf(lambda row: len(row))
df = df.withColumn('length_list',length_list(col('list')))
df.show()
+--------------------+---+-----------+
|                list|  A|length_list|
+--------------------+---+-----------+
|[23, 4, 77, 890.455]| 10|          4|
|   [11, 2, 50, 1.11]| 20|          4|
|   [10.05, 1, 22.04]| 30|          3|
+--------------------+---+-----------+
```

Comment: Your answer is partially right.Still the list will be a string,not a proper list.Giving it you though.Thank you!

Comment: Well, it will be string and I had noticed that using `df.PrintSchema()`, but it will behave like a proper list and you could add it, where as the original list you cannot add because it is a proper string. I tested the code before answering it.

Comment: Apply thus `UDF` - `udf(lambda row: sum(row))` on both the old list and the new list. You will see the difference. Former will give an `Error`, and later will give `sum`.

Comment: I need to find the length of the first element of 'list'. Can I do it with current string representation?

Comment: Any other method ? cph_sto

Comment: I know this one. If one can do it directly, I am not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a string, you could remove the first and last characters:
From `'[23,4,77,890,455]'` to `'23,4,77,890,455'`
Then apply the `split()` function to generate an array, taking `,` as the delimiter.

Answer (score -2):

Please use the below code to ignore unicode

```
df.rdd.map(lambda x: x.encode("ascii","ignore"))
```

Comment: Would'nt it give the same error as above: rdd has no attribute 'encode'?